# A non well formed numeric value encountered in - setcookie function

Tags: php, datetime

```
            $user_id = $row['UserID'];
            $token = uniqid($user_id,TRUE);
            $salt = md5(mt_rand());
            $cookie_id = hash_hmac('SHA512',$token,$salt);

            $nextWeek = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
            $expiry = date('Y-m-d', $nextWeek);
            //Problem exists here               

            $sql_store_cookie = "INSERT INTO pcookies(cookie_id,user_id,expiry,salt) values('$cookie_id','$user_id','$expiry','$salt')";
            mysqli_query($connection,$sql_store_cookie) or die(mysqli_error($connection));//die('{"l":"mysqli_error(`$connection`)"}');
            setcookie($cookie_id,$token,$expiry);
```

If i run the above program, i am getting `non well formed numeric value warning` in `setcookie` line. I hope i am using the correct format of type.

My timezone setting is Asia/kolkata
And expiry data type is timestamp.

I am trying to set 7 days from the current time.

Please tell me what i am doing wrong here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read [the manual](http://php.net/setcookie), you will see this box for the third parameter

> **Note:**
>      You may notice the expire parameter takes on a Unix timestamp, as opposed to the date format Wdy, DD-Mon-YYYY HH:MM:SS GMT, this is because PHP does this conversion internally.

So you need to do the following instead

```
setcookie($cookie_id,$token,$nextWeek);
```

Comment: No. Timestamp format, exactly what you are doing with `$nextWeek = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)`, which will result in a number (eg _1430650370_) and not a string (eg _2015-05-03_)

Comment: Why? `setcookie()` does not want it converted and if I understood you correctly, your db does neither

Comment: `string(10) "1430652019"`
`Incorrect datetime value: '1430652019' for column 'expiry' at row 1`